# How to make the an Android Vector asset for an ImageView non-transparent

Tags: android, android-imageview

I crated a Vector asset using Android studio and I have the following code:

```
<vector android:height="24dp" android:tint="#4CAC78"
    android:viewportHeight="24" android:viewportWidth="24"
    android:width="24dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <path android:fillColor="@android:color/white" android:pathData="M23,12l-2.44,-2.78 0.34,-3.68 -3.61,-0.82 -1.89,-3.18L12,3 8.6,1.54 6.71,4.72l-3.61,0.81 0.34,3.68L1,12l2.44,2.78 -0.34,3.69 3.61,0.82 1.89,3.18L12,21l3.4,1.46 1.89,-3.18 3.61,-0.82 -0.34,-3.68L23,12zM13,17h-2v-2h2v2zM13,13h-2L11,7h2v6z"/>
    
</vector>
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

The problem is that the exclamation mark is transparent and I would like to make it non-transparent. I tried to change the attribute `path android:fillColor="@android:color/black`but this did not have any effect. Any idea how I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The green area and the exclamation mark are really created by two separate paths that are combined into the single `path` statement in the vector drawable. To color them separately, you need to separate them out into separate path statements:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24"
    android:viewportHeight="24">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#4CAC78"
        android:pathData="M23,12l-2.44,-2.78 0.34,-3.68 -3.61,-0.82 -1.89,-3.18L12,3 8.6,1.54 6.71,4.72l-3.61,0.81 0.34,3.68L1,12l2.44,2.78 -0.34,3.69 3.61,0.82 1.89,3.18L12,21l3.4,1.46 1.89,-3.18 3.61,-0.82 -0.34,-3.68L23,12z" />
    <path
        android:fillColor="@android:color/black"
        android:pathData="M13,17h-2v-2h2v2zM13,13h-2L11,7h2v6z" />
</vector>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Cheticamp for your answer. It works fine and I accepted and upvoted it. However, I have a question regarding the splitting of the one path. How did you know where to split the path? In the vector asset created by android studio you have the path `<path android:fillColor="@android:color/white" android:pathData="M23,12l-2.44,-2.78 0.34,-3.68 -3.61,-0.82 -1.89,-3.18L12,3 8.6,1.54 6.71,4.72l-3.61,0.81 0.34,3.68L1,12l2.44,2.78 -0.34,3.69 3.61,0.82 1.89,3.18L12,21l3.4,1.46 1.89,-3.18 3.61,-0.82 -0.34,-3.68L23,12zM13,17h-2v-2h2v2zM13,13h-2L11,7h2v6z"/>`. Where shall this be splited

Comment: @VanessaF You are right: There is more that can be removed from the first path statement. What I initially posted created the polygon and two exclamation marks - one from the first path and one from the second. I deleted characters from the end of the first so that only one mark is created.

Comment: @VanessaF [Here](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/understanding-androids-vector-image-format-vectordrawable-ab09e41d5c68) is a good description of the language of vector drawables.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Cheticamp. But generally speaking, when I create a vector asset via Android Studio, how can I know where to split the paths such that the vector asset is non-transparend without learning this very complex vector language?

Comment: @VanessaF That is going to vary by vector drawable,. In this drawable, I looked for the "move" commands (`M`) at the end of the path and deleted from each move command to the end until only the polygon remained. I then pasted what I had deleted as a new path and changed the colors. It was trial and error and not very scientific. For a more complex drawable, I would consider importing the drawable into an SVG editor, making the changes and importing the SVG back into Android Studio. There may be vector drawable editors available now, but I haven't looked in some time.